# Is there a way to remove only the followed duplicates?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a CSV input with these columns:

```
1,zzzz,xxxx,
1,xxxx,xyxy,
2,xxxx,xxxx,
3,yyyy,xxxx,
3,xxxx,yyyy,
3,xxxx,zzzz,
1,ffff,xxxx,
1,aaaa,xxxx,
```

And I need to discard lines where the first field matches that of the preceding line:

```
1,zzzz,xxxx,
2,xxxx,xxxx,
3,yyyy,xxxx,
1,ffff,xxxx,
```

I tried `sort | uniq` alone but didn't work because all lines are different with exception of first field (number).

Comment: Did you try just `uniq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` instead of `uniq`:

```
awk -F, '$1 != last { last=$1; print }'
```

`-F,` sets the field separator to comma. `$1` is the contents of the first field, so this prints the line whenever the first field changes.

Comment: I'm sorry i edited the question to better explain the situation, using only uniq, i will get everything because some parts of each line are unique so it makes every line unique even though the first part is repeating.

Comment: I've posted a new answer using `awk`.

Comment: Your solution is better since it selects all the field and not just part of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Got the wanted output with `uniq --check-chars=N`; the `uniq` will check only a specified number of characters in the lines, and since the input isn't sorted this will allow the characters to appear later on the list.

Comment: Good solution, if you have a fixed-width first field - are yours all the same length?

Comment: The first field have between 7 and 8 characters, checking the first 5 was enough for me .